# Проблема с отображением динамически добавленых элементов в родительский элемент находящийся в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Задача такая:  отобразить список "treeResult" в RecyclerView, причем по нажатию на элемент списка, должен отобразиться другой список "treeResult.getSubChildrens()", который может состоять из заранее неизвестного количества элементов.

Для решения задачи использовал ExpandableRelativeLayout (по нажатию на нее, она сдвигает элементы под собой, отображая собственный контент) и реализовал метод динамического добавления элементов в родительский контейнер находящийся в ExpandableRelativeLayout.

Возникла следующая проблема, при запуске приложения, все данные находятся на своих местах и отображаются корректно. Но если пролистать список вниз, открыть некоторые ExpandableRelativeLayout и вернуться обратно, можно обнаружить, что отображение элементов стало некорректным (где-то вместо трех элементов отображается два, а где-то появляются пустые артефакты).

Насколько мне позволяют судить знания о работе RecyclerView, ошибка находится в методе bindCrime класса ViewHolder. Но никак не удается решить проблему. Если убрать "container.removeAllView", то дочерние элементы уже начинают меняться местами в хаотичном порядке, при использовании данного метода, они хотя бы остаются на месте.

Наглядное описание текущего состояния приложения:

1. Приложение только запущено, нажимаем на элементы списка. Все корректно.
2. Листаем до конца вниз, и видим, что последний элемент открылся сам собой + он содержит только два элемента, но место выделено под три.
3. Листаем до конца вверх, корректное отображение нарушено, вместо трех элементов отображаются только два (причем во время дебага метод "addChildView" выполняется три раза, как и должно быть).
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. считаю, что метод "setIsRecyclable(false)" не является решением проблемы, т.к. скорость работы RecyclerView существенно снижается.

Код адаптера:

```
public class AdapterRecycler extends
```

RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private ArrayList<RootJsonObject> treeResult;
private Context context;
public AdapterRecycler(ArrayList<RootJsonObject> treeResult) {
    this.treeResult = treeResult;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    this.context = parent.getContext();
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_recycle_view, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final RootJsonObject rootTree = treeResult.get(position);
    holder.bindCrime(rootTree);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return treeResult.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView textView;
    private LinearLayout rootContainer;
    private ExpandableRelativeLayout expandableRelativeLayout;
    private LinearLayout container;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        rootContainer = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rootContainer);
        expandableRelativeLayout =
                (ExpandableRelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandableLayout);
        expandableRelativeLayout.toggle();

        container = (LinearLayout)expandableRelativeLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.containerContent);

        rootContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                expandableRelativeLayout.toggle();
            }
        });
    }

    public void bindCrime(RootJsonObject rootTree) {
        textView.setText(rootTree.getTitle());

        container.removeAllViews(); // если не удалять старые View,
                                    // то они начинают перемешиваться друг с другом
        if (rootTree.getSubChildrens() != null) {
            Iterator<RootJsonObject.SubChildren> iterator = rootTree.getSubChildrens().iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                RootJsonObject.SubChildren subChildren = iterator.next();
                int id = subChildren.getId();
                String title = subChildren.getTitle();

                addChildView(container, id, title);
            }
        }
    }

    private void addChildView(LinearLayout container, int id, String title) {
        View childView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_expandable_layout, null, false);
        TextView tvId = (TextView) childView.findViewById(R.id.text_id);
        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) childView.findViewById(R.id.text_title);

        tvId.setText(String.valueOf(id));
        tvTitle.setText(title);

        //для наглядности подкрашиваем созданные View
        Random rand = new Random();
        childView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(rand.nextInt(200), rand.nextInt(200), rand.nextInt(200)));

        container.addView(childView);
    }
}
```

}

Код разметки элемента RecyclerView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/rootContainer"
android:padding="@dimen/item_recycle_padding"
tools:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/item_recycle_height"
        android:padding="@dimen/item_recycle_padding"
        tools:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_folder"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Test"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/expandableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:ael_duration="300"
        app:ael_expanded="false">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/containerContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>
    </com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вы знаете, вью в `RecyclerView` во время скролла переиспользуются, что и приводит к таким ошибкам. Чтобы элементы произвольно не открывались/закрывались во время скролла, вам нужно сохранять состояние каждого элемента и восстанавливать во время биндинга. Например, как это сделано в [примере](https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/jp/android/aakira/sample/expandablelayout/examplerecyclerview/RecyclerViewRecyclerAdapter.java) библиотеки, которую вы используете:

```
private SparseBooleanArray expandState = new SparseBooleanArray();
...
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    ...
    holder.expandableLayout.setExpanded(expandState.get(position));
    ...
}
```

На счет решения второй проблемы, с размером раскрывающегося элемента, не уверен, но возможно, поможет явная установка `LayoutParams` во время биндинга, чтобы размер пересчитался заново:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
container.setLayoutParams(params);
```

**Но** я бы на вашем месте пошёл другим путём. Раз уж вы решили использовать библиотеку, то лучше попробовать одну из тех, которые созданы именно для вашей задачи [ExpandableRecyclerView](https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=ExpandableRecyclerView). Их предостаточно на сегодняшний день.

Comment: К сожалению, явная установка LayoutParams не решила проблему размера родительского элемента. Но благодарю за ответ, теперь буду смотреть в сторону специальных библиотек.

Comment: Есть ещё вариант установить точный размер родительского элемента. То есть взять высоту одного ребёнку, помножить на их кол-во и установить в `LayoutParams` вместо `WRAP_CONTENT`

Comment: Попробовал такой вариант. Все равно, если открыть много вкладок, то начинаются ошибки в размере родительского контейнера. Все как на скриншотах выше.